# Reduced Residue System in Mathematica

Tags: elementary-number-theory, mathematica, reduced-residue-system

How can I create the standard reduced residue system modulo $m$ in Mathematica for a given positive integer $m$? For example, if I input $10$, I would like it to give me the list $\{1,3,7,9\}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This would be more appropriate on mathematica.stackexchange.com but, for the time being:

```
residueSystem[n_Integer?Positive] := 
  Select[Range[n], GCD[#, n] == 1 &];
residueSystem[10]

(* Out: {1, 3, 7, 9} *)
```